Problemas al sumar columna de un Tablelayout
Muy buenas comunidad esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, mira siguiendo con mi primer app para android studio, estoy realizando el ingreso de datos para ser mostrados en un tabledlayout la cual esta perfectamente bien, una vez terminado el ingreso se debe realizar la suma de una coluna especifica, que es la ultima y se realiza de esta manera:
private void sumarColumnas() {
    txtpromedio.setText("0");
    int sum = 0;
    int rowCount = tbldatos.getChildCount();

    for (int i = rowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        View registro = tbldatos.getChildAt(i);
        EditText colAjustado = registro.findViewById(R.id.colAjustado);
        if (colAjustado != null) {
            String valueStr = colAjustado.getText().toString();
            if (!valueStr.isEmpty()) {
                int value = Integer.parseInt(valueStr);
                sum += value;
            }
        }
    }
    txtpromedio.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    cmdsuma.setEnabled(false);
    txtajuste.requestFocus();
}

el oroblema que me surje es que siempre colAjustado = null, no lo entiendo si lo tengo bien declarado es variable tanto en el xml de la tabla14:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/fila1"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colFilas"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/item"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:textColorHint="#757575"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colDetalle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text="Detalle"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colAno"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="Año"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colValor"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="Valor"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colDep"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="Dep."
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/colAjustado"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:importantForAutofill="no"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:text="Ajustado"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    tools:ignore="TouchTargetSizeCheck" />


si se dan cuenta lo tengo bien y este mismo ,o utilizo para mostrar los datos en la tabla a traves de un arreglo:
private void buscar(){
    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    tbldatos.removeAllViews();
    String url = "http://192.168.1.90/oficina/buscar_valor1.php?N_Siniestro=" + txtsiniestro.getText().toString();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
            tableDynamic.addData(getClients());
            tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
            tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.RED, Color.YELLOW);
            tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
            tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.WHITE);
            tableDynamic.textColorHeader(Color.MAGENTA);
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    LayoutInflater reg1 = getLayoutInflater();
                    View registro = reg1.inflate(R.layout.tabla14, null, false);
                    colFilas = registro.findViewById(R.id.colFilas);
                    colDetalle = registro.findViewById(R.id.colDetalle);
                    colAno = registro.findViewById(R.id.colAno);
                    colValor = registro.findViewById(R.id.colValor);
                    colDep = registro.findViewById(R.id.colDep);
                    colAjustado = registro.findViewById(R.id.colAjustado);
                    String id = jsonObject.getString("ID");
                    colFilas.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Filas"));
                    colDetalle.setText(jsonObject.getString("Detalle"));
                    colAno.setText(jsonObject.getString("Año_Vehiculo"));
                    colValor.setText(jsonObject.getString("Valor_Vehiculo"));
                    colDep.setText(jsonObject.getString("Depreciacion"));
                    colAjustado.setText(jsonObject.getString("Valor_Ajustado"));
                    registro.setTag(id);
                    tbldatos.addView(registro);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}

si se dan cuanta es solo el problema cuando utilizo para sumar las columnas si siempre es colAjustado = null ya llevo varios días en este problema, además se me olvido mencionar que dicho proceso lo realizo en un activity, antes este caso se realizo el mismo proceso de sumar columnas en un fragment y me funciona al 100%, así que puede ser ese el problema, me refiero que a un activity no se puede realizar dicho proceso de sumar columnas, ojala que me puedan ayudar y desde ya muchas gracias

Como comentas el problema es que colAjustado  tiene valor null, esto se puede evitar verificando si el objeto registro es de tipo tableLayout, realiza el siguiente cambio:
private void sumarColumnas() {
    txtpromedio.setText("0");
    int sum = 0;
    int rowCount = tbldatos.getChildCount();

      for (int i = rowCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            View registro = tbldatos.getChildAt(i);
            if (registro instanceof TableRow) { //* Verifica
               EditText colAjustado = registro.findViewById(R.id.colAjustado);
                /*if (colAjustado != null) {
                   String valueStr = colAjustado.getText().toString();
                   if (!valueStr.isEmpty()) {
                       int value = Integer.parseInt(valueStr);
                       sum += value;
                   }
               }*/
              if (colAjustado != null && !colAjustado.getText().toString().isEmpty()) { //* Realiza operación
                sum += Integer.parseInt(colAjustado.getText().toString());
              }


           }
        }

    txtpromedio.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    cmdsuma.setEnabled(false);
    txtajuste.requestFocus();
}


Muy buenas amigos del foro, leyendo e investigando llegue a la siguiente conclusión que en los fragment es viable y factible 100% en mencionar el nombre de la Columna que uno ingresa en el xml, en cambio en los activity es viable mencionar siempre el numero de la columna, por lo cual realice este proceso de esta manera, primero en el botón el siguiente código:
cmdsuma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sumarColumnas();
        }
    });

posteriormente se dirige uno al private:
private void sumarColumnas() {
    txtpromedio.setText("0");
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < tbldatos.getChildCount(); i++) { // el i siempre en 1 ya que si lo coloca uno en 0 cuenta el encabezado de la tablelayout
        View row = tbldatos.getChildAt(i);
        if (row instanceof TableRow) {
            TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) row;
            TextView cell = (TextView) tableRow.getChildAt(5); // Índice 5 para la sexta columna
            sum += Integer.parseInt(cell.getText().toString());
        }
    }
    txtpromedio.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
    if (cmdmodificar.isEnabled()) {
        int val3 = Integer.parseInt(txtitem1.getText().toString());
        int val5 = Integer.parseInt(txtfilas.getText().toString());
        int val4 = Integer.parseInt(txtpromedio.getText().toString());
        int resta = (val3 - val5);
        long re1 = (val4 / resta);
        txtpromedio.setText(String.valueOf(re1));
        cmdsuma.setEnabled(false);
        txtajuste.requestFocus();
    } else {
        int val3 = Integer.parseInt(txtitem.getText().toString());
        int val4 = Integer.parseInt(txtpromedio.getText().toString());
        long re1 = (val4 / val3);
        txtpromedio.setText(String.valueOf(re1));
        cmdsuma.setEnabled(false);
        txtajuste.requestFocus();
    }
    cmdmodificar.setEnabled(false);
    btn_eliminar1.setEnabled(false);
}

con este proceso lo relazo muy bien y no me crea problemas, ojala que les sirva para algunos usuarios que también están empezando en este mundo del android studio
